# Kohana globals being cleared?

Tags: php, kohana, global-variables

I wrote a question earlier trying to get around using a controller in Kohana, but I gave in and rewrote the file.  So now, the I have this php script inside a Kohana controller.  The view that the controller is rendering is 'requiring' a php file so I can perform some third-party functions. I was having a major issues with it and got to debugging.  The problem seems that functions inside the included file cannot access variables outside the function from within that same file. It seems that Kohana is clearing the globals somehow???

example:

```
//controller.php
require_once("ccfunctions.php");

//ccfunctions.php
$test = 'something';
function test(){
  global $test;
  echo $test;
}
test();
//This does not produce anything
```

Any thoughts on this one?

EDIT:
Actually, the above example doesn't work even from my view file that is being rendered.  Forget the included file.  I realize Kohana tries to enforce the MVC model, but this is ridiculous.  Why cannot I not create a function and call a global variable from within my view file?

Comment: You can... There must be something else wrong.  What you are describing is exactly what helper files do so why it's not working for you is probably caused by a problem not related to Kohana, but I could be wrong.  Interested to know what the problem is either way.  Have you tried echoing a string literal in your `test` function to see if the function itself it being called?

Comment: @Endophage: a string literal displays fine from within the function.  Bizarre.  Tearing my hair out over here ;)  I've not used Kohana before, this is a takeover project.  So far it's been fine, but this is really bothering me.

Comment: your issue has nothing to do with kohana specifically, but has to do with understanding of variables visibility scope.

Comment: @Endophage.  Yes, I didn't understand how that was being handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `global` for variable in both cases:

```
//controller.php
require_once("ccfunctions.php");

//ccfunctions.php
global $test;
$test = 'something';
function test(){
  global $test;
  echo $test;
}
test();
//This does not produce anything
```

Btw, it is really weird practice and I believe there are workarounds for any case without using `global`

Comment: specifying "global" from the string declaration produces a parse error.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use globals. Why use an OOP framework when you want to use globals?

Comment: Wasn't my choice.  Why use a framework at all if you have to spend hours reworking code to fit the MVC model?

Comment: @Senica Gonzalez: kohana **does fit** MVC model

Comment: I know, that's what I said.  But other code doesn't always fit that model.  Anyways, it doesn't matter.